# Blank Image when loading from remote url

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Everything seemed to work fine, however when I try to load an image from remote url, it shows up blank on debug device. This is when deploying from VS on Windows to physical iPhone device.

It works fine in iOS simulator and Android emulator.

Tried the following:

```
image.Source = new Uri(url);
image.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(url));
```

As well as things like loading the image from stream using ImageSource.FromStream

My best guess is it has got something to do with permissions?! But the app seemingly connects just fine with the server API. Why would it have any trouble loading image from the same server?

*Update:
It seems the problem only exists when debugging from Windows (Using Xamarin Hot Restart). Deploying the same project from a Mac didn't cause the same error. Hoping for a fix to this specific issue, as developing on Windows is my personal preference.*

Comment: Did you check your connection ?

Comment: have you tried loading that same url in the device browser?

Comment: @cahyo Yes, it's connected. As mentiond in the post, it connects to the server API just fine.

Comment: @Jason Yes, the url works fine. Also tried other external image urls from other websites, same issue.

Comment: Did you use **http** ?

Comment: @cahyo Nope. Only using https.

Comment: Does Release build (and start without debugger) behave the same?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Didn't try with Release build. Seemed pointless to try as the process is pointless unless debugging.

Comment: It might be pointless. Normally I wouldn’t suggest it. But its so surprising that it works deploying from Mac but not pc, that I’m trying to think of what could be different. If Release build works, that might be a clue. I recommend `adb uninstall com.yourcompany.yourapp` to be sure nothing left behind from a previous debug deploy. factory reset device, so know its in a clean state. Power off at minimum.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The problem is on physical iPhone device. Not the android emulator or iPhone simulator. Release build didn't fix the issue either. For now I'm just forced to sync the code to my Mac when I need to test on device, and just stick with simulator on Windows PC for quick debugging.

Comment: This localized failure is quite surprising. Sounds like different version of some code - might be worth deleting pc's nuget cache, to be sure something isn't corrupted. With delete bin/obj folders for total clean rebuild.